# Use sed/cat to add text from 1 file after matched pattern in multiple files

Tags: sed, cat

I need to add text from 1 file to multiple files between 2 tags. all files have same extension .sh but different names and all all in subdirectorys.

i tried modify this but its only working for search and replace:

```
file=$(cat file1.txt)
replace="s/end=date +%s/$file/g";
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "$replace"
```

file1.txt

```
some text here
some text here
some text here
some text here
some text here
```

final output and content of file1.txt added as new line below end=date +%s to all .sh files

```
end=date +%s
some text here
some text here
some text here
some text here
some text here
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Since you managed to get it done for one, can you paste the code snippet for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read list of files on unix and run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028643/read-list-of-files-on-unix-and-run-command)

Comment: Sorry my bad, i updated the question with what i tried but not working

Comment: Do you REALLY want to `add text from 1 file to multiple files between 2 tags` or do you actually just want to append the contents of a file after 1 tag? What should the script do if `/dir/$tag.tar.gz` is present but the next line isn't `end=\`date +%s\``?

Comment: Yes, the text in the file1.txt is a lot and needs to be inserted to any .sh file between /dir/$tag.tar.gz and end=`date +%s`,

Comment: So if `/dir/$tag.tar.gz` is present but the next line is not `end=\`date +%s\`` then the contents of `file1.txt` should NOT be inserted, right?

Comment: To make it easier, just insert content of file1.txt in any .sh file after /dir/$tag.tar.gz tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try gnu sed on bash shell, testing it without -i option;

```
sed -E '/end=date\s+\+%s/r file1.txt' *.sh
```

after testing add -i option to real edit e.g. `sed -Ei`....
to search files in subs recursively, use `find` to do so and the found files are sent to sed
find ~+ -iname '*.sh' -exec sed -E '/end=date\s++%s/r file1.txt' '{}' +

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unterminated `s' command any idea? i changed my question and its better to insert on a new line after: end=date +%s

Comment: it seem not to work for subdirectorys but only for files in the same directory, any advice?